# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Rails 4.2.7.1

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

On my local system, I am facing an error of Statement Invalid. Previously, I was not getting this, but I think when I reindexed my elastic search after adding the taxon_ids index, this error started to come. Please check the attached screenshot.
[image: error_img]

And version details are -

```
Mysql - 5.7.34-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
Rails - 4.2.7.1
Ruby  - 2.3.1
```

Please advise on how it can be resolved.

Comment: Can you show the table definition and the values of the arguments being passed in? Anonymized of course :D

Answer (score -1):

The Error says that your Database is missing some columns. Can you run
`rake db:migrate`